# Javascript: Access slider value

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to access the values from this slider (http://sujeetsr.github.io/d3.slider/) for a chart that will appear before the sliders on the same page.

```
<body>
    <script>
        function onload(){
             var test = getDocumentElementById('test').value
             alert(test)
        }
    </script>
    ...
    <h4> Slider 1 </h4>
    <div id='test'></div>
    ...
    <script>
        var slider = d3.slider().min(0).max(1).ticks(1).showRange(true);               
        d3.select('#test').call(slider);
    </script>

</body>
```

I am unable to access the slider value. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oddly enough, it seems like this isn't well documented. Here's what I found: You can either add a callback to catch the value or call the **value()** function with no argument to get the current value:

```
var slider = d3.slider()
      .min(0)
      .max(10)
      .showRange(true)
      .value(5)
      .callback(function(evt) {
        //fired every time the value changes
        logger.debug('callback: ' + self.slider.value());
      });

d3.select('#myslider').call(slider);
var currentVal = slider.value(); //manually get the current value
```

Answer (score 1):

the slider object returns the value by calling it's value() function, it doesn't bind it to the div. So you need to keep the slider in the scope you want to use it, and access it's value in Javascript from the slider object itself.

```
var slider = d3.slider().min(0).max(1.0).ticks(10).showRange(true);

document.getElementById('showButton').addEventListener('click', function(){
     alert(slider.value());
})
```

It also supports adding a callback function, this will be called whenever you slide it.

```
var slider = d3.slider()
        .min(0)
        .max(1.0)
        .ticks(10)
        .showRange(true)
        .callback(function(a){
                   console.log(slider.value()); // <-- this will call when you slide
                 });
d3.select('#test').call(slider);
```

Here is a JSFiddle illustrating the use cases:
https://jsfiddle.net/workingClassHacker/0wgps84y/8/